# Big expansion boards for ticket to ride

Tags: ticket-to-ride, custom-game-pieces

I enjoy giving anniversary or otherwise "nicer" editions of games to family and friends.  Last year for Christmas, I got my sister and brother-in-law a copy of [Ticket to Ride 10th Anniversary Edition](http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/anniversary/inside/).  It was a bit more expensive than the basic version, but I felt it was well worth it.  They have played the game on a regular basis ever since and have not yet seen the (much) lower quality pieces of the basic releases.

That being said, I have been looking towards the future and what the next gift will be and I would love to find some of the additional maps (such as Asia, Legendary Asia, India, etc...) in the larger size as to accommodate the larger pieces.

---

- Are there such larger maps available anywhere?  (even if only as pnp)
- Are the regular sized maps too small to use the anniversary pieces?

---

This image from bgg would make it seem that the answer to the second question is an unfortunate yes, but have people tried using them anyways and have any experience with doing so?  Allowing the pieces to either hang off the edge or placing them slanted, etc...?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Getting your own made, could work.](http://www.boardgamesmaker.com/customized/custom-gameboard.html)

You would likely need a high quality image.

The other potential issue would be the legality of it, but if they/you already own the map it could be [legal in the UK and the EU](http://copyrightuser.org/topics/private-copying/) (I am not a lawyer, and cannot give advice on this issue and, besides, I don't know which country's laws are most relevant to you).