# Pieces to use with expansions

Tags: ticket-to-ride

I've bought the anniversary editions of both standard (USA) and the Europe versions of Ticket to Ride (TTR), and was thinking of donating the standard versions to charity.

But then I got to think about having pieces for use with the expansion (I have all the map expansion packs, that's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6½ and 7), the pieces from the anniversary editions are a bit larger so they probably won't fit - but I also have TTR Germany and TTR Märklin, are there enough pieces in (either of) those, that I wouldn't make my expansions hard to use?

Comment: With regards to bigger pieces and fitting: [I had asked a similar question a while back](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25177/big-expansion-boards-for-ticket-to-ride).  The general consensus is that they don't fit sadly.

Comment: With regards to quantity of pieces, the components listing in the front of the rulebooks should tell you how many pieces are included in each box or are needed.  My understanding is that most maps require 45 cars in each color with the exceptions requiring less.  Märklin should have the required 45 for each color plus a few spares and so should have all the pieces you would need.

Comment: Team Asia requires 54 trains of each color.  Also, we replaced the plastic trains with (heavier) wooden trains of the same size, which makes for a nicer playing experience IMO.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't pose a problem as such, because the expansion contains 9 extra train pieces in each of the five colours used in USA or Europe, using Germany or Märklin as base, just means that I only have 54 trains in black, red and yellow, but as Team Asia is for up to three teams, that's sufficient. And who are "we"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is a surprising: No - well 12 out of 13 maps pose no problems, but the 13th does; But as I had posed the question it's technically a yes.

First of all: I had seen he question JMoravitz refers to in a comment, but that only confirmed my suspicion that the pieces from the anniversary editions are a bit too large.

I just went through all the expansions and none required any thing besides up to 45 (some only 40 and some only 35) train pieces in each colour and 110 train cards (a few contained replacements for those), and both the Märklin and Germany editions contain that - but there is a problem:
The "old west"  map is playable by up to 6 players and for that it contains white train pieces, which don't conflict with the red+yellow+purple+blue+green pieces of USA or Europe, but both Märklin and Germany contains pieces in red+yellow+purple-black+*white*. So if I only kept those, I wouldn't have train pieces in 6 different colours to play the "old west" map with 6 people.

I could probably switch the white pieces in "Germany" ("Märklin" also contain scoring markers with a different design) for the blue/green pieces in USA/Europe. I'll probably have to go through all the expansions again (and more closely) to see if that will cause any problems.

Comment: The outlined switch would give a fourth colour that could be used for playing "Team Asia", that's not needed though, and I'm considering switching the green/blue trains from USA/Europe for the white pieces in "old west", that would only affect "old west".